# Why does Eywa reject Grace's body to her avatar?

Tags: plot-explanation, avatar

In *Avatar* Grace has a positive attitude and mindset towards the Navi people.

Then why does Eywa reject her body to the avatar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [this site](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Grace_Augustine), you can read that (emphasys mine):

> In a trance-like state, the Na'vi and Mo'at prayed in the hope that
>   Eywa would permanently transfer Grace's consciousness to her avatar
>   body. **Unfortunately, she succumbed to her wound**, but before she passed
>   away, Grace told Jake that she was with Eywa.

So she actually died before the cerimony was complete, but her consciousness survived and lives now within Eywa.